# Ajax fail but message is sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hey guys I am trying to send a message through form craft plugin but i get this error "jquery.js:4 POST http://www.Myurl.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 504 (Gateway Time-out)" and these details

```
send        @   jquery.js:4
ajax        @   jquery.js:4
(anonymous) @   booking_modal.js:3
dispatch    @   jquery.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.js:3
```

But message is sent even if i get 'Ajax fail' error. What should i do? I am looking for a solution but cant figure out one. Also in custom.js:1791 undefined error there is this code. Should i change anything?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        /*  Show mini cart */
        $('#show-mini-cart-button').click(function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            $(this).parent().find('.traveler-cart-mini').toggleClass('open');
            return false;
        });

        $('.i-check').on('ifChanged', function(){
            var t = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){ // I GET THE ERROR HERE I THINK
                var url = t.data('url');
                console.log( url );
                if (url) {
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    });
```

I am new to this... If you need any other option please let me know or don't get mad if don't do right question please.. Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: The request is sent, but it never recives a response, hence why it times out. There's nothing wrong with the clientside code, other than it doesn't seem to contain any ajax calls?

Comment: Why this times out? Is there any way to find that?

Comment: adeneo is right...where is the ajax call? check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It times out because the server never responds. Why it does that is impossible for us to know, all we see is the clientside code?

Comment: adeneo can you please let me know if is possible nad which file should i upload so you take a look? whould be admian-ajax.php good resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the URL you are redirecting to on your own site? You should be able to check Apache (or NginX) logs, or PHP error_log.

It looks like this is not the code causing your problem. Your error was

```
jquery.js:4 POST http://www.Myurl.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 504 (Gateway Time-out)
```

However, your code above that redirects is:

```
window.location.href = url;
```

That is just calling a URL, which means you are sending a GET request there.

Chek in the Firefox Web Inspector network panel to see what request is being fired, and which headers/vars were sent. That way you should be able to find your offending code and continue debugging.

Comment: I did it delboy and my results are:request url: http://www.----------.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 2)method Post 3) status code 504timeout gateway

Comment: Ok, look through the javascript for code that does a POST to admin-ajax.php